# How to restrict android player from playing more than one media file parallely?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

If I play a music in other app, e.g. foobar2000

And then use this function to play music in my app, two players will play at the same time

```
public void playMusic(String file){
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+file);

    if(uri!=null) {
        myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                myPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build());
        }else{
            myPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
        try {
            myPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        try {
            myPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        myPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

If I play music in my app first, and then play other player, the other players still cannot stop my player

If I try other two player apps, they can stop each other.

How can I force Android to play my player only, and allow other player to stop my player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AudioManager class as below,
whenever u need audio focus, call below method

```
protected fun requestAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        val audioManager: AudioManager = binding.root.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

        val res = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mFocusRequest = AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
                    .setAudioAttributes(mPlaybackAttributes)
                    .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
                    .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(afChangeListener)
                    .build()
            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(mFocusRequest)
        } else {
            audioManager.requestAudioFocus(afChangeListener,
                    // Use the music stream.
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    // Request permanent focus.
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
        }
        return res == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
    }
```

whenever you want to release it use code below,

```
val audioManager: AudioManager = binding.root.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocusRequest(mFocusRequest)
            } else {
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(afChangeListener)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        }
```

In manifest u need to ask permission for modifying audio settings

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Note :- code snippet is in Kotlin